# Como fazer recursiva em SQL server usando WITH para retornar todos os filhos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando fazer uma recursiva em uma única tabela chamada local em que tem um localSuperior ID, referenciando a mesma tabela.

Se eu tenho o meu lugar maior com o ID 1664, ao fazer a recursiva, ele me retorna os lugares abaixo desse lugar.
Porém, eu precisava que me retornasse os lugares abaixos dos filhos também, como fazer?

Segue meu código:

```
WITH lugar AS 
(
    SELECT l.[Id], [l].[LocalSuperiorId], l.[Nome]
    FROM [RM].[Local] AS [l]
    WHERE [l].[LocalSuperiorId] IN (1664
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT l2.[Id], l2.[LocalSuperiorId], l2.[Nome] 
    FROM [RM].[Local] AS [l2]
    INNER JOIN lugar p ON p.[LocalSuperiorId]=[l2].[Id]
) 
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM lugar
WHERE lugar.[LocalSuperiorId] IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, as expressões utilizando WITH são chamadas de CTE's (Common Table Expressions).
Você precisa de uma CTE recursiva. Você fez bem a união de duas queries com o UNION.

1) O que você precisa é que a primeira query da UNION represente o caso inicial, como você já fez, e a segunda query represente o caso recursivo, com uma pequena modificação.

```
WITH lugar AS 
(
    SELECT 1 [nivel], l.[Id], [l].[LocalSuperiorId], l.[Nome]
    FROM [RM].[Local] AS [l]
    WHERE [l].[LocalSuperiorId] IN (1664)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT lugar.nivel+1 [nivel], l2.[Id], l2.[LocalSuperiorId], l2.[Nome] 
    FROM [RM].[Local] AS [l2]
    INNER JOIN lugar p ON p.[Id] = [l2].[LocalSuperiorId]
) 
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM lugar
WHERE lugar.[LocalSuperiorId] IS NOT NULL
```

Fiz uma alteração na sua condição

```
INNER JOIN lugar p ON p.[LocalSuperiorId]=[l2].[Id]
```

para

```
INNER JOIN lugar p ON p.[Id] = [l2].[LocalSuperiorId]
```

Pois o caso inicial da CTE começa na raiz (primeiro nível), e o caso recursivo pega o que está abaixo, então é o nível de baixo que aponta para o local superior, e não o contrário.

Coloquei também uma coluna "nivel", que vai retornando o nível de profundidade em que nos encontramos na hierarquia, pode ser interessante.

2) Sua query, do jeito que está, não retorna o departamento raiz, com seu nome, dados, etc. O departamento 1664. Não seria interessante exibi-lo? Caso sim, basta uma pequena alteração.

```
WITH lugar AS 
(
    SELECT 0 [nivel], l.[Id], [l].[LocalSuperiorId], l.[Nome]
    FROM [RM].[Local] AS [l]
    WHERE [l].[Id] IN (1664)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT lugar.nivel+1 [nivel], l2.[Id], l2.[LocalSuperiorId], l2.[Nome] 
    FROM [RM].[Local] AS [l2]
    INNER JOIN lugar p ON p.[Id] = [l2].[LocalSuperiorId]
) 
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM lugar
WHERE lugar.[LocalSuperiorId] IS NOT NULL
```

3) Por fim, você não deveria precisar dar um SELECT DISTINCT no final, pois supostamente cada departamento não pode aparecer mais de uma vez na hierarquia. Bastaria um SELECT comum. Se um departamento aparecesse mais de uma vez no resultado final, só poderia haver duas possibilidades. A primeira é que um departamento pertencesse a mais de um departamento superior. Este caso não ocorre devido à sua modelagem de tabelas só permitir o identificador de um único departamento superior. A outra possibilidade é que um departamento contivesse outro, que por sua vez contivesse outro, e assim por diante, até chegar em um departamento que contém o departamento de origem. Isto indicaria uma circularidade na definição das referências, o que é uma inconsistência e sua query ficaria em loop.

Além disso, não é necessário testar "WHERE lugar.[LocalSuperiorId] IS NOT NULL", pois no caso inicial, ele satisfaz à condição "WHERE [l].[LocalSuperiorId] IN (1664)", e jamais pode ser nulo; e no segundo caso, ele satisfazer o join com algum outro registro, então o que foi retornado jamais pode ser nulo, também.

Então a query final ficaria assim:

```
WITH lugar AS 
(
    SELECT 0 [nivel], l.[Id], [l].[LocalSuperiorId], l.[Nome]
    FROM [RM].[Local] AS [l]
    WHERE [l].[Id] IN (1664)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT lugar.nivel+1 [nivel], l2.[Id], l2.[LocalSuperiorId], l2.[Nome] 
    FROM [RM].[Local] AS [l2]
    INNER JOIN lugar p ON p.[Id] = [l2].[LocalSuperiorId]
) 
SELECT *
FROM lugar
```

Um problema interessante, seria ordenar o resultado de forma a mostrar a estrutura hierárquica, isto é, para cada registro retornado, os registros seguintes seriam seus subdepartamentos alfabeticamente, e assim por diante.